# Google Cast SDK3 Android sample app is crashing on device below 5.0

Tags: android, google-cast

Ive tried the Google Cast Android sample app, and  is crashing for device below 5.0.
Anyone has any idea why? below is my crash log:

08­30 12:38:57.242: E/AndroidRuntime(16269): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
08­30 12:38:57.242: E/AndroidRuntime(16269): at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni.zzbg(Unknown Source)
08­30 12:38:57.242: E/AndroidRuntime(16269): at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni.zza(Unknown Source)
08­30 12:38:57.242: E/AndroidRuntime(16269): at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.﻿
没有加一

Comment: Is this a real device that you are testing, or an emulator? Does it have the appropriate Google Play Services?

Comment: I used a real device, samsung one, I think it has the appropriate google play services, and its the google sample app...

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a change in the latest Cast SDK that made it incompatible (crashing) with older versions of Google Play Services.
Unfortunately, even cast sample app crashes when using latest Cast SDK with outdated GPS (or on emulators).
The issue has been discussed here: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/issues/12

The solution is to check Google Play Services version before initialising any cast components, including mini controller (i.e. you can't just put mini controller fragment into your xml layout file - you either have to inflate it dynamically, or have two layout files - one with, and one without your mini controller).

Code to check GPS version:

```
GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
isGPSAvailable = (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS);
```

If the results is not `ConnectionResult.SUCCESS`, don't initialise your `MiniControllerFragment` and do not access `CastContext`.

Also, please keep in mind that it is **not** possible to instantiate `MiniControllerFragment` using `new MiniControllerFragment()`. You have to inflate it from xml or you will get `NullPointerException`.

There are two ways to inflate `MiniControllerFragment`:

1. Create separate xml layout files and inflate appropriate one in your `Activity.onCreate`:

   ```
   setContentView(isGPSAvailable ? R.layout.activity_main_with_controller : R.layout.activity_main_without_controller);
   ```
2. Create `ViewStub` in your layout pointing to `MiniControllerFragment` and inflate it only when you have play services.

activity layout:

```
<ViewStub
android:id="@+id/cast_minicontroller"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout="@layout/cast_mini_controller_fragment"
/>
```

cast_mini_controller_fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/castMiniController"
          class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:visibility="gone"/>
```

code in your activity `onCreate()`:

```
ViewStub miniControllerStub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.cast_minicontroller);
if (isGPSAvailable) {
    miniControllerStub.inflate();
}
```

I prefer the `ViewStub` approach as it does not duplicate your layouts.