# Getting Google Cast v3 to work on unsupported devices

Tags: android, chromecast

The Cast V3 framework has features which try to make it possible to run on devices without the `Google Play Services` required for it to work, but I ran into some issues when testing.

1. On the Kindle the Google API returns SERVICE_INVALID with a isUserResolvable() true.
2. On devices with the onActivityResult returning `ConnectionResult.SUCCESS` after upgrade, the `CastContext.getSharedInstance()` can throw `RuntimeError`.
3. As a side-effect of 2), the XML inflate of items containing `MiniControllerFragment` will fail.

Some errors I found were

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{##########.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class fragment

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: Remote load failed. No local fallback found.
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzauj.zzan(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzauj.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.uicontroller.UIMediaController.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
```

This was caused by the inflation of the MiniControllerFragment, on a device where the `CastController` code wasn't installed.  This is similar to the question asked [SO : Cast v3 is crashing on devices below 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313189/google-cast-sdk3-android-sample-app-is-crashing-on-device-below-5-0).  The answer provided by Kamil Ślesiński helped in my investigation.

and

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=123, result=0, data=null} to activity #####
```

When I had implemented my ViewStub, I was still crashing in the pre-release test machines, as they were returning SUCCESS, but didn't have the CastContext available.  To fix this, I needed another test to check if the CastContext was creatable.

Comment: How did you solve your problem? By checking GoogleServices Version?

Comment: onCastResultReceived creates a CastContext in a try block.  If this fails, then it does not make Cast Available.  I have tried to edit the answer to clarify this.

Comment: I am not using your solution though. In general, I am asking that what's the cause for your mentioned problem?

Comment: My activity got a SUCCESS code in the OnActivityResult, but the embedded GPS UI crashed when inflating.  Given it was failing to create a CastContext, creating one before enabling the inflate allowed me to predict the result.

Comment: In my case, It's hard to reproduce. I am getting SUCCESS code as well.
Few of the devices are getting this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a singleton / code in the Application something like below....

```
boolean gCastable = false;
boolean gCastTested = false;
public boolean isCastAvailable(Activity act, int resultCode ){
    if( gCastTested == true ){
        return gCastable;
    }

    GoogleApiAvailability castApi = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int castResult = castApi.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(act);
    switch( castResult ) {
        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
            gCastable = true;
            gCastTested = true;
            return true;
     /*  This code is needed, so that the user doesn't get a 
      *
      *  your device is incompatible "OK" 
      *
      * message, it isn't really "user actionable"
      */
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID: // Result from Amazon kindle - perhaps check if kindle first??
            gCastable = false;
            gCastTested = true;
            return false;
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        default:
            if (castApi.isUserResolvableError(castResult)) {
                castApi.getErrorDialog(act, castResult, resultCode, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        gCastable = false;
                        gCastTested = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }).show();
            } else {
                gCastTested = true;
                gCastable = false;
                return false;
            }
    }
    return gCastable;
}

public void setCastOK(Activity mainActivity, boolean result ) {
    gCastTested = true;
    gCastable = result;
}
```

and a helper function to check if we know the state of the cast.

```
public boolean isCastAvailableKnown() {
    return gCastable;
}
```

However to cope with devices which return SUCCESS, I also needed the following code in the App / singleton.

When the Activity receives the cast result, we create a `CastContext`.  The "hope" is, if the Application can create the `CastContext`, then the framework will succeed in the same way (the cause of the crash).

```
public boolean onCastResultReceived( Activity act, int result ) {
    boolean wasOk = false;
    if( result == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS ){
        try {
            CastContext ctx = CastContext.getSharedInstance(act );
            wasOk = true;
        } catch ( RuntimeException e ){
            wasOk = false;
        }
    }
    if( wasOk ) {
        setCastOK(act, true);
        return true;
    }else {
        setCastOK(act, false );
        return false;
    }
}
```

The inflation of the mini controller is disabled by using a `ViewStub` and a fragment...

Fragment mini_controller_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cast_mini_controller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:castShowImageThumbnail="true"
    class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment" />
```

With usage something like this....

```
    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/cast_mini_controller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout="@layout/mini_controller_fragment"
        />
```

### Activity

An Activity's interaction with the `cast` components looks something like this...

```
/* called when we have found out that cast is compatible. */
private void onCastAvailable() {
    ViewStub miniControllerStub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.cast_mini_controller);
    miniControllerStub.inflate();    // only inflated if Cast is compatible.
    mCastStateListener = new CastStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCastStateChanged(int newState) {
            if (newState != CastState.NO_DEVICES_AVAILABLE) {
                showIntroductoryOverlay();
            }
            if (mQueueMenuItem != null) {
                mQueueMenuItem.setVisible(
                        (mCastSession != null) && mCastSession.isConnected());
            }
        }
    };
    mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);
    if (mCastSession == null) {
        mCastSession = mCastContext.getSessionManager()
                .getCurrentCastSession();
    }
    if (mQueueMenuItem != null) {
        mQueueMenuItem.setVisible(
                (mCastSession != null) && mCastSession.isConnected());
    }
}


private void showIntroductoryOverlay() {
    if (mOverlay != null) {
        mOverlay.remove();
    }
    if ((mediaRouteMenuItem != null) && mediaRouteMenuItem.isVisible()) {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mOverlay = new IntroductoryOverlay.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this, mediaRouteMenuItem)
                        .setTitleText(getString(R.string.introducing_cast))
                        .setOverlayColor(R.color.primary)
                        .setSingleTime()
                        .setOnOverlayDismissedListener(
                                new IntroductoryOverlay.OnOverlayDismissedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onOverlayDismissed() {
                                        mOverlay = null;
                                    }
                                })
                        .build();
                mOverlay.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

onCreate modified as below...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mApp = (MyApplication)getApplication();
    if( mApp.isCastAvailable( (Activity)this, GPS_RESULT )) {
        onCastAvailable();
    }

    ...
}
```

onActivityResult needs to cope with the result from the Google Play Services upgrade...

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( requestCode == GPS_RESULT ) {
        if(mApp.onCastResultReceived( this, resultCode ) ){
            onCastAvailable();
        }
```

onResume

```
protected void onResume() {
    if( mCastContext != null && mCastStateListener != null ) {
        mCastContext.addCastStateListener(mCastStateListener);
        mCastContext.getSessionManager().addSessionManagerListener(
                mSessionManagerListener, CastSession.class);
        if (mCastSession == null) {
            mCastSession = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this).getSessionManager()
                    .getCurrentCastSession();
        }
        if (mQueueMenuItem != null) {
            mQueueMenuItem.setVisible(
                    (mCastSession != null) && mCastSession.isConnected());
        }
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

onPause

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if( mCastContext != null && mCastStateListener != null ) {
        mCastContext.removeCastStateListener(mCastStateListener);
        mCastContext.getSessionManager().removeSessionManagerListener(
                mSessionManagerListener, CastSession.class);
    }
}
```

The session Manager listener in the class...

```
private final SessionManagerListener<CastSession> mSessionManagerListener =
        new MySessionManagerListener();
private class MySessionManagerListener implements SessionManagerListener<CastSession> {

    @Override
    public void onSessionEnded(CastSession session, int error) {
        if (session == mCastSession) {
            mCastSession = null;
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionResumed(CastSession session, boolean wasSuspended) {
        mCastSession = session;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStarted(CastSession session, String sessionId) {
        mCastSession = session;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStarting(CastSession session) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStartFailed(CastSession session, int error) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionEnding(CastSession session) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionResuming(CastSession session, String sessionId) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionResumeFailed(CastSession session, int error) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionSuspended(CastSession session, int reason) {
    }
}
```

### UI interaction

Finally I could change the UI when cast was available by calling the "known" function in my Application...

```
    int visibility = View.GONE;
    if( mApplication.isCastAvailableKnown( ) ) {
        CastSession castSession = CastContext.getSharedInstance(mApplication).getSessionManager()
                .getCurrentCastSession();
        if( castSession != null && castSession.isConnected() ){
            visibility = View.VISIBLE;
        }
    }
    viewHolder.mMenu.setVisibility( visibility);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just put the viewstub inflation within a try catch and observe whether or not it fails?

Comment: @AndreasRudolph that would make it less clear if the Cast was available, and may break some of the UI elements if they are not handling the catch properly.  I felt I had better control over the result if I only inflated the ViewStub if I expected it to work.

Comment: You are right, I suppose it is a matter of a big proper solution vs. a smaller but-not-as-targeted solution. One can choose oneself - Thank you for the help!