# No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cast-sdk, android-cast-api

After adding Bitmovin Cast in Android project I get a lot of same issues from different devices.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313189/google-cast-sdk3-android-sample-app-is-crashing-on-device-below-5-0) solution didn't help.

```
GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getContext())
```

- returns 0 (SUCCESS)

But app crashes.

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zze.zzf(Unknown Source:51)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zze.zza(Unknown Source:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.(Unknown Source:37)
       at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(Unknown Source:6)
       at com.bitmovin.player.BitmovinPlayer.(SourceFile:106)
       at com.bitmovin.player.BitmovinPlayer.(SourceFile:82)
       at com.bitmovin.player.BitmovinPlayer.(SourceFile:71)
       at com.bitmovin.player.BitmovinPlayerView.(SourceFile:134)
       at com.bitmovin.player.BitmovinPlayerView.(SourceFile:120)
```

So, Google Play services version is ok.

Answer (score 9):

According to [this](https://www.e-learn.cn/content/wangluowenzhang/650546) article code like this can help:

```
fun isCastApiAvailable(): Boolean {
    val isCastApiAvailable = isNotTv(context)
            && GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS
    try {
        CastContext.getSharedInstance(context)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // track non-fatal
        return false
    }
    return isCastApiAvailable
}

fun isNotTv(Context context): Boolean {
    UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) context.getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE)
    return uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() != Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION
}
```

But in my case, this is [Bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com) issue

Comment: isNotTv not found anywhere

Comment: Good answer but I think the TV check can be done better with `!context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LEANBACK)`

Answer (score 6):

It's because either your device or emulator has an out-dated version of Google Play services. Right above your error you should see something in the log cat that says

```
Google Play services out of date. Requires 3264100 but found 3225132
```

**Just update the Google Play services and it'll work.**

source https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/issues/97

Comment: In my case I was literally running on an android emulator which didn't have Google Play services

Comment: It's not possible for the app developer to update play services.  The answer is an end-user answer, not a developer answer.

Comment: @MikeMacpherson You can first check if Google Services are up to date, and in case it's deprecated - just ask the user to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using a emulator or flashed device, try testing on a normal play services updated device, should work.