# Firebase data not displaying in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to display data using Firebase in an app made with flutter. This had worked until a few hours ago, after which it stopped working despite no change in my code. I get the following warnings:

```
W/DynamiteModule( 3174): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 3174): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 3174): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/TetheringManager( 3174): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.icse_quizapp
I/le.icse_quizap( 3174): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/le.icse_quizap( 3174): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
D/nativeloader( 3174): classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86:/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86:/product/lib:/system/product/lib
W/ProviderInstaller( 3174): Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader;->pathList:Ldalvik/system/DexPathList; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->systemNativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)        
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryPathElements:[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->makePathElements(Ljava/util/List;)[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
V/NativeCrypto( 3174): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller( 3174): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (greylist, JNI, allowed)
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/le.icse_quizap( 3174): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

Can someone please help me and tell me what is going wrong?

EDIT: I am using a Pixel emulator on Android Studio. I have already ensured that Google Play services is installed, there is no update available, I have made sure that `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` is there in each AndroidManifest.xml file and that the main one also has `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`, and in my build.gradle I have the following:

```
minSdkVersion 30
targetSdkVersion 21
multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: please provide some code do you think your error is there in it

Comment: My code is divided in many files, hence I haven't provided it, but I don't think it has to do with my code because it has run properly once already with the same code. It stopped working without me modifying anything.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: I just rewrote my code the exact same way and it worked. I still don't know the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by turning on and off my Emulator Wi-Fi and Mobile data.

Comment: Worked perfeclty. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

there is many solution here:
[Flutter firestore platform exception](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27719)

solution 1-You might need to update the Play service on your phone/emulator.

solution 2-or ensure the emulator/device has play service installed
[No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542514/no-acceptable-module-found-local-version-is-0-and-remote-version-is-0)
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/QDaAHIH3vzQ

solution 3-cheek permission: ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE in your manifest file

solution 4-try upgrading the min supported android version in build.gradle

Comment: I have tried all of these solutions. Nothing has worked.

Comment: cheek your  firebase Role

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: see my new answer

Answer (score 0):

check your firebase Rules and change the date if it ends it maybe takes 5 min to have an effect.

the image below displays how you can reach it

[image: Firestore Database Rules]

[image: Realtime Database Rules]

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error: Error saving rules - Line 1: mismatched input '{' expecting {'function', 'import', 'service', 'rules_version'}

Comment: also, how might this make a difference??

Comment: check your firebase Rules NOT change it like me its  difference.

Comment: I just want to know what your rules

Comment: oh sorry i did not understand

Comment: it is the same as the first picture of yours `rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 9, 14);
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this problem for 2 days nothing can solve it. I just figured out the Solve is very easy just log in to your google play account it will do. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this hadn't worked for me :(