# Cant access firebase/firestore when cloning flutter project to another computer

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have uploaded my project on github and cloned to another computer. It compiles fine but it hasnt got access to Firbase/firestore and therefore i cant use this cloned project properly with authentication and so on.
Do I have to change something when I clone a flutter app with firebase to another computer to make it work and gain access to the database and  the authentication?

**Errormessage:**

```
D/EGL_emulation(10634): app_time_stats: avg=6275.84ms min=9.86ms max=106419.61ms count=17
D/EGL_emulation(10634): app_time_stats: avg=11.48ms min=5.31ms max=40.71ms count=60
D/EGL_emulation(10634): app_time_stats: avg=9.29ms min=4.92ms max=16.29ms count=56
D/EGL_emulation(10634): app_time_stats: avg=8.66ms min=5.06ms max=15.26ms count=61
D/EGL_emulation(10634): app_time_stats: avg=9.94ms min=4.58ms max=24.23ms count=61
D/EGL_emulation(10634): app_time_stats: avg=10.22ms min=5.13ms max=20.02ms count=60
D/EGL_emulation(10634): app_time_stats: avg=8.59ms min=4.91ms max=15.28ms count=60
D/EGL_emulation(10634): app_time_stats: avg=8.31ms min=5.03ms max=16.29ms count=61
D/EGL_emulation(10634): app_time_stats: avg=8.91ms min=4.52ms max=14.01ms count=61
D/EGL_emulation(10634): app_time_stats: avg=9.90ms min=4.90ms max=17.99ms count=60
I/flutter (10634): 2 false
D/EGL_emulation(10634): app_time_stats: avg=9.15ms min=5.06ms max=22.87ms count=60
D/EGL_emulation(10634): app_time_stats: avg=83.28ms min=12.88ms max=1016.12ms count=15
W/Firestore(10634): (24.4.0) [WatchStream]: (24ebbad) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
W/DynamiteModule(10634): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(10634): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(10634): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

It happend to be that the android emulator on my other computer was a bad version where firebase didn’t work correctly.
I only had to downgrade from android emulator 31.3.10 then everything worked fine.

This video shows how:
https://youtu.be/qo3SbdbXFos

Answer (score 0):

this could have many reasons.

1. Check your GitIgnore maybe some Firebase config files were not uploaded to Github and are therefore missing in the cloned project.
2. Check your Firebase security rules. Check how you are allowed to access your DB.

If this didn't work, provide the thrown error, please.

Comment: It shoudnt be the security rules since I auth doesnt work neither which hasnt got any security rules. I can add that I have uploaded the app on a test version on playstore and it also works diffrent physical devices. I have updated the post with gitignore and errormessage, maybe you can see the issue?

Comment: I have tested the internet connection with a network image which  shows that it works fine on the emulator

Comment: The error code is quite generic. This might help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73399202/firebase-data-not-displaying-in-flutter-app 
also check if you have flutterfire configured correctly.

Comment: I found the solution, it was a bad version of the android emulator, I posted the answer.